# ERROR: Could not build wheels for Kivy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, windows, cmd, kivy

I've been trying to install kivy on windows10 machine and I did not get an expected output, instead, I got a series of weird error messages. First I ran the following commands:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
python -m pip install kivy.deps.angle
python -m pip install pygame
```

And as far as I know, everything went right.

After that, I ran this command: `python -m pip install https://github.com/kivy/kivy/archive/master.zip`

Command output helped me break down the process of executing it.

First I got an error message while "Getting requirements to build wheel".

error message: [image]

I got this error while "Preparing wheel metadata" and "Building wheel for Kivy (PEP 517)" as well. I think that it is worth mentioning that every time I said that error occurred, it occurred twice, one after another.

After that, I got a huge error:

You can download the test file with an error message on this link: https://filesend.standardnotes.org/send/BPQTjNM3aiUyRXOtfA3A#ZGI2ZDUzMWU2MmYzNTlhNTVlODEw

Note: All the commands that I executed were executed in cmd ran by the administrator.

If anyone can explain to me what is going on I would highly appreciate it!

Comment: Can you try replacing your first cmd with `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` and see if the error still persists

Comment: Have you solved it? Do update on your status

Comment: The problem is solved, thanks to everyone!

Comment: Glad to hear marko

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going by related issues here - [ERROR: Could not build wheels for pendulum which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60920252/error-could-not-build-wheels-for-pendulum-which-use-pep-517-and-cannot-be-insta) and [pip failing to build wheels for scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441549/pip-failing-to-build-wheels-for-scipy)

The answers seem to suggest that downgrading `pip` version will likely solve the problem. But before that please try

`pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`

Instead of

`python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools`

and see if it solves. If not, downgrade your `pip` by doing

```
python -m pip install --force-reinstall pip==18.1
```

If none of these work then your only viable solution is to use `Kivy` within `Anaconda`. You can see more on installation from [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/kivy).

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, this error means that you are trying to run 64-bit application on a 32-bit system. Install python version which corresponds to your OS, and then try again.

Also, make sure you have the newest version of C++ Redistributable installed.

Comment: Hmm, it could be. Do you have any source for this or have you encountered this yourself?

Comment: @AzyCrw4282 The error seemed familiar and when I googled the code, I remembered that I had incompatible versions (32/64bit) and since the python modules could rely on C++ libraries, it is good to update C++ Redistributable just in case. Also I agree he should try with `Anaconda` if none of these work.